# assign standard tolerance to isequal funtion Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am Using matlab 2012b, I came through a some simple problem when using the function isequal. I have to round the floating values. but, I got some basic errors because of some exceptions.

In my file the values are rounded to nearest integer in most cases. but, they are some exceptions like

if i have a variable value

```
a = X.4675
```

it has been rounded to X in many cases but there few cases it has been rounded to X+1.

my task is just to compare and check the equality. In this case it should be true in both X and X+1 cases. hence, I need to modify isequal function with a tolerance of 1.

```
isequal({b1, b2, b3, b4},{B1, B2, B3, B4})
```

b1, b2... are values after rounding the original, B1, B2 ....are standard values to camapare. now I want to give a tolerance of 1

B1 = round(b1)|| B1 = round(b1)+1

Note: B1,B2.... values are standard, I need to compare all at a once.

Comment: So, `result = all(abs([b1 b2 b3 b4]-[B1 B2, B3, B4])<=1)`?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11305-springlab?focused=5074772&tab=function

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15816-isalmost

Comment: Thank you, both serve the purpose@LuisMendo, @TwistedSim